Typescript issue and reducer state doesn't add use on click. Property 'state and dispatch' does not exist on type 'UserContextType | null'
I am new to typescript with react and tried so many thing but doesn't work. state doesn't work and getting typescript error  Property 'state and dispatch' does not exist on type 'UserContextType | null'
UserContRed.tsx
export const UserContRed = () => {

   //const context = useContext(ContRedContext)
    const {state , dispatch } = useContext(ContRedContext)
   
    const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState('')
    const [id, setId ] = useState(0)
    const [lastname, setLastname] = useState('')
 
    // let displayUsers =  context?.state.users.map( (u:any) => {
    let displayUsers =  state.users.map( (u:any) => {
        return(
            <ul key={u.id}>
                <li>{u.id}</li>
                <li>{u.firstname}</li>
                <li>{u.lastname}</li>
            </ul>
        ) 
    }) 
    const addUser = () => {
        const addUser = () => dispatch({type:ActionType.ADD, payload : {id:1,firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname}})
    }

    return(
        <div>
          <div>
            <label>Id: </label>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setId(Number(e.target.value))}} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Firstname: </label>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setFirstname(e.target.value)}} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Lastname: </label>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setLastname(e.target.value)}} />
          </div>
            <button onClick={addUser}>sendToStore</button>

          
        </div>
       
    )
}

ContRed.tsx

export type User = {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string; 
}

type contredProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode
}


export type IuserState = {
    users : User[]
}
const initialState: IuserState = {
    users : [
        {
            id:0,
            firstname:'',
            lastname: ''
        }
    ]
}
export enum ActionType {
    ADD="add",
    REMOVE="remove"
}


type  userAction = {
    type: ActionType,
    payload: User
}


export const reducer = (state: IuserState, action: userAction) : typeof initialState  => {
    
    switch(action.type){
        case "add": 
                return ({...state, users: [...state.users,
                                                    {id:action.payload.id,
                                                     firstname:action.payload.firstname,
                                                     lastname:action.payload.lastname   
                                                    }
                                                ]
                        })
        case "remove": 
                        return ({...state, users: [
                                    ...state.users.filter(data => data.id !== action.payload.id)]
                                })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


type UserContextType = {
    state: IuserState
    dispatch: React.Dispatch<userAction>
}

export const ContRedContext = createContext<UserContextType|null>({
    state:initialState,
    dispatch: () => {}
})



export const ContRedContextProvier = ({children}:contredProps) => {
    
    const[state,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,initialState as IuserState);
    const value : UserContextType = { state, dispatch}
    
    return(
        <ContRedContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </ContRedContext.Provider>
    )

}

App.tsx
    <ContRedContextProvier>
        <UserContRed/>
    </ContRedContextProvier>
    

I tried with using constant instead de-structuring typescript error goes away but it doesn't add or doesn't update the state. typescript is so hard seems to me with react please explain or guide what i am doing wrong.
Below tried typescript is fine but functionality doesn't work
  const context = useContext(ContRedContext)
  let displayUsers =  context?.state.users.map( (u:any) => { ...}
   const addUser = () => context?.state.dispatch({type:ActionType.ADD, payload : {id:1,firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname}})

Tried:
 const context = useContext(ContRedContext)
  let displayUsers =  context?.state.users.map( (u:any) => { ...}
   const addUser = () => context?.state.dispatch({type:ActionType.ADD, payload : {id:1,firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname}})

Expected:
User should add to state and render in child component.

You have typed the ContRedContext to be nullable, e.g. createContext<UserContextType | null>({ .... }) , so consumers would need to use a null-check prior to accessing state or dispatch.
Example:
const context = useContext(ContRedContext);

if (!context) return null;
  
const { state, dispatch } = context; // not null 

But you don't appear to ever pass a null context value, even for the default context value, and likely have no need to.
Update the ContRedContext context type declaration to remove the null type:
export const ContRedContext = createContext<UserContextType>({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: () => {}
});

There is an additional issue in the UserContRed component with the addUser handler. It declares a function that issues the dispatch and never calls it.
Issue code:
const addUser = () => {
  const addUser = () => // <-- never called
    dispatch({
      type: ActionType.ADD,
      payload: { id, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname }
    });
};

Update to just call dispatch:
const addUser = () => {
  dispatch({
    type: ActionType.ADD,
    payload: { id, firstname, lastname }
  });
};


Thanks for the quick response, removing null take care of the typescript error but state (dispatch) doesn't work it seems it doesn't fire the action or reach to reducer

seems  removing null take care of it. Thank you so much

@QuestForKnowledge There was another issue in the UnserContRed component code with the addUser handler. I've updated the answer to address.
